# Spark parsing pipe delimited file incorrectly

Tags: pyspark

Had a process that reads .csvs just fine.  We need to switch the delimiters due to how some of the data is being sent.  Tried to do the following change:

Current

```
df = spark.read.option("header", "true") \
      .option("delimiter", ",") \
      .option("inferSchema", "false") \
      .csv("file")
```

Proposed

```
df = spark.read.option("header", "true") \
      .option("delimiter", "|") \
      .option("inferSchema", "false") \
      .csv("file")
```

However this is parsing the file incorrectly.  When I call a .printSchema() on the df,

I see the following:

```
root
 |-- col1,col2,col3,col4: string (nullable = true)
```

It seems as if it's failing to parse the columns individually.  I've tried .read.csv, and some other variants and I'm running into the same issues regardless how how I'm bringing in the data.

Comment: Try "\\|" as delimiter

Comment: I had actually tried that before.  Error was "unsupported special character for delimiter"

Comment: Looks like your code is right. But your file might be correupted. You have to check if both the header and all records are actually pipe separated. If not, consider replacing all ',' with '|'. Though this is a costly operation, it is still better than loosing data. Else consider posting a sample of the problamatic data you are working with

Comment: I thought it was the data as well but I manually counted the pipes to ensure it was adding up.  Unfortunately doing a replace for all ',' is not ideal as some column values will have commas in the data.